# Como puedo pasar datos a traves de ui-view (ui-router)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy usando los nested y named views de ui-router.

Lo que quiero lograr es poder pasar un dato desde el div que invoca a un template al template en si.

Algo como esto:

```
<div ui-view="inputtext" data-value="0"></div>
<div ui-view="inputtext" data-value="1"></div>
<div ui-view="inputtext" data-value="2"></div>
```

Usar el mismo template en todos los casos pero pasandole un valor diferente a cada uno.

Asi serian los estados:

```
.state('project', {
      url: "/project/:projectId",
      views: {
        'project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/project.html"
        },
        'group@project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/group.html"
        },
        'task-1@project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/task-1.html"
        },
        'inputtext@project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/modules/inputtext.html"
        }
      }
```

Dentro de 'project' hay varios 'group', dentro de 'group' hay varios 'task' y dentro de task es que quiero mostrar varios inputtext pero con diferentes valores.

Comment: Técnicamente sólo estás usando `named views` en tu ejemplo, `nested views` es cuando tienes la notación `state: 'padre.hijo'` o una configuración `parent: 'padre'` en la definición del estado. Si entendí correctamente tienes un estado con 4 fragmentos que muestran información del proyecto. Me parece que lo que quieres lograr se puede lograr fácilmente con una sola vista `inputtext@project` y un `ng-repeat` que muestre toda la información. En mi opinión la solución que quieres es compleja sin motivo alguno.

Answer (score 1):

Este código es parte de un proyecto que realicé y un ejemplo para que te guíes.

En primer lugar debes definir un parámetro que recibirá la vista por GET

```
function myApp($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('category', {
        url: '/category/:categoryId',
        templateUrl: './frontend/app/search/category/category.html',
        controller: 'category',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
}
```

En este caso es `categoryId`. Luego hacer un función en el controlador de la vista de donde vas a mandar los datos para ir a la vista y mandar los datos.

```
$scope.redictCategory = (select) => {
    $state.go("category", {
        categoryId: select
     });
}
```

Si lo notas, yo me muevo entre las vistas por el método `.go` del servicio `$state` y ahí paso los datos como un objeto JSON, que recibe como parámetro la vista, como lo expliqué en el código anterior.